# Webservice with java android

Tags: java, android, web-services

I have the following web service and i want to ask how i can retrieve following value.

These are the input values

```
<soap:Body>
    <getWeight xmlns="http://tempuri.org/">
      <patientID>int</patientID>
      <batchTimeStamp>string</batchTimeStamp>
      <value>double</value>
    </getWeight>
  </soap:Body>
```

and this is the response xml

```
 <getWeightResponse xmlns="http://tempuri.org/">
      <getWeightResult>
        <message>string</message>
        <code>int</code>
      </getWeightResult>
      <value>double</value>
    </getWeightResponse>
  </soap:Body>
```

my java code in order to request the data is

```
request.addProperty("patientID", PatientId);//"8");//PatientID);
request.addProperty("batchTimeStamp", TimeStamp);
request.addProperty("value", "2");
```

ok my question is it possible to get the double from the response?, until this time i get only the message and code.
someone else developed the webservice and there is no manual or comments and i try from nothing to check what is working

Answer (score 0):

Try to use [KSOAP](http://ksoap2.sourceforge.net/).

```
httpTransport.call("Generate", envelope);
oSoapObjectResult = (SoapObject) envelope.bodyIn;
if (oSoapObjectResult != null)
{
     sGenerate = oSoapObjectResult.getProperty("GenerateResult").toString();
}
```

Comment: It's also possible to request and fetch response using Native classes.

Comment: am using KSOAP and as i write above am getting in the result only the message and code but i also want and the value

Comment: my question is not answered yet. just my question is if is possible to retrieve the value variable and not just the message and code variables

Comment: it might be need pointer in order to access the value variable?